# Let $H = \{g \in S_6 : g(a)\equiv a\pmod3 \text{ for } a\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}.$ Is this a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, symmetric-groups

Let $H = \{g \in S_6 : g(a)\equiv a\pmod3 \text{ for } a\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}.$ Is this a subgroup?

The identity element $\in H$ because for all $a \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, we have $h(a) ≡ a\pmod3$ as $h(a)-a=a-a = 0$ and $3|0$.

For closure, let $g,h \in H$. Then for all $a \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, we have $g(a)\equiv a\equiv h(a)\pmod3$. So for all $a \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, $(gh)(a)=g(h(a))$. Now this is where I am unsure how to proceed!!

I try for inverses anyway. Let $h \in H$. Then $h(a)\equiv a\pmod3$, so $h^{-1}(h(a))=\ldots$

Can I have some help please ?

Comment: $H$ is finite, closure suffices.

Comment: @Devo That doesn't necessarily mean the condition will hold under composition though ?

Comment: I meant, you can forget about inverses.

Comment: @Devo Okay thanks. What would you do for closure then ?

Comment: Just as before, you need to specify what it is a subgroup of.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept an answer, @NikitaMazepin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [finite subgroup test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Finite_Subgroup_Test).

You have $e\in H$, so $H\neq \varnothing$.

By definition, $H\subseteq S_6$.

For closure, suppose $g,h\in H$. Then for all $a\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, we have $\color{blue}{g(a)\equiv 
 a}\pmod{3}$ and $\color{red}{h(a)\equiv a}\pmod{3}$. Now

$$\begin{align}
(gh)(a)&=g(\color{red}{h(a)})\\
&\equiv g(\color{red}{a}\pmod{3})\\
&\equiv\color{blue}{g(a}\pmod{3}\color{blue})\\
&\equiv\color{blue}{a}\pmod{3},
\end{align}$$

so that $gh\in H$.

Hence $H$ is a subgroup of $S_6$

Comment: Thanks! Should some of the equal signs be replaced by congruence equivalences though ?

Comment: You're welcome, @NikitaMazepin, and yes, you're right. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) shouldn’t the equals become congruences when defining $g$ and $h$ as well ?

Comment: You're welcome, @NikitaMazepin, and yes, I have made the necessary edit.

Comment: What is the difference between the 2nd and 3rd line of working ? I.e. what is the meaning of the extra blue brackers ?

Comment: There's no difference, @NikitaMazepin; it's just a matter of emphasis on my part.

Answer (score 3):

Hint.

Try to prove that
$$H=\langle(14),(25),(36)\rangle\tag1$$

In general, the following statement is true.

> Let $n$ and $m$ be positive integers and $X=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. If
> $H=\{g\in S_n\mid g(a)\equiv a\pmod m\forall a\in X \}$, then $H$ is a
> subgroup in $S_n$.

*Proof.*
Let $X_i=\{a\in X\mid a\equiv i\pmod m\}$, $i=0,1,\ldots,m-1$.

Now the set $H$ can be described by another $H=\{g\in S_n\mid g(X_i)=X_i\}$.

It seems obvious to me now that $H$ is a subgroup.

PS. If $n=6$, $m=3$, then $X_0=\{3,6\}$, $X_1=\{1,4\}$, $X_2=\{2,5\}$.
In this case $H$ is defined by the formula $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

For finding the inverse, note that for all $a \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, $h(a) \equiv a \pmod{3}$. This means that $a - h(a)$ is divisible by $3$. Since $h^{-1}$ is also in $H$, $h^{-1}(h(a)) \equiv a \pmod{3}$. This implies that $h^{-1}(h(a)) - a$ is divisible by $3$. This means that $h^{-1}(h(a)) = a + 3k$ for some integer $k$. Thus, $h^{-1} \in H$ and $H$ is a subgroup.

Comment: so you can just state that the composition of the inverse $h$ and $h$ is congruent to $a$ mod $3$ like you did without any further explanation ?