# Let $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ & $H=\{g\in S_6:g(i)-g(j)\equiv i-j\mod 3\text{ for all }i,j\in\Omega\}\subset S_6 ={\rm Sym}(\Omega).$ Show $H\le S_6$.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

I am unsure with how I laid my answer out, in particular for the 2nd and 3rd requirements

> Let $\Omega =\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Let $H =\{g \in S_6 : g(i) - g(j) \equiv i-j \mod 3\text{ 
>  for all }i,j \in \Omega\} \subset S_6 ={\rm Sym}(\Omega).$ Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $S_6$.

**I am not allowed to use the finite subgroup test**

$SG0$ - identity element $\in H$. $e$ is the identity function so for all $i,j \in \Omega$, $e(i) = i$ and $e(j)=j$. So, for all $i,j \in \Omega$, $e(i)-e(j) = i - j \equiv i-j \mod 3$ as required. So $e \in H$.

$SG1$ - for all $g,h \in H$, $gh \in H$ (closure). Let $g,h \in H$, so for all $i,j \in \Omega$, $g(i) - g(j) \equiv i-j \mod 3$, and $h(i) - h(j) \equiv i-j\mod 3$. Then, $gh = g(h(i)-h(j)) \equiv h(i)-h(j) \mod 3\equiv i-j\mod 3$ as required. So $gh \in H$.

$SG2$ - for all $h \in H$, we have $h^{-1} \in H$. Let $h \in H$, so for all $i,j \in \Omega$, $h(i) - h(j) \equiv i-j\mod 3$. Now, $h(h^{-1}(i)-h^{-1}(j))\equiv h^{-1}(i)-h^{-1}(j)\mod 3$. Thus, $i-j \equiv h^{-1}(i)-h^{-1}(j)\mod 3$, so $h^{-1}(i)-h^{-1}(j) \equiv i-j\mod 3$. So $h^{-1} \in H$.

So all requirements satisfied so $H$ is a subgroup of $S_6$. I am mainly unsure on my notation for the 2nd and 3rd requirement. Can someone please check this?

Comment: You can stop after closure.   That's the *finite subgroup test*.

Comment: @eggnog I understand that but in my class I have to check these 3 requirements separately. Can you please check that they are correct?

Comment: Use `$a\equiv b\mod n$` for $a\equiv b\mod n$.

Comment: Also, it's `$\{ x\}$` for $\{ x\}$. You should know this by now. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594285/let-h-g-in-s-6-ga-equiv-a-pmod3-text-for-a-in-1-2-3-4-5-6-i?rq=1). The "finite subgroup test" is so basic, that one should not forbid it.

Comment: Well it seems to be correct;   though you did cut a corner or two. I mean you wrote $gh$, instead of $gh(i)-gh(j)$.  Similarly on the last part.  You'll get better at writing these things out, with practice.

Comment: @eggnog thank you so much because that was exactly what I was confused on, although I didn't make it clear enough. I was getting confused because there were $2$ variables rather than $1$. I'll write it down fully now. Thanks. What should I have wrote down for the last part ?